# kotlin get a simple message using retrofit

Tags: json, kotlin, retrofit

Hello i am having big problems here this is my first time using retrofit and i am new to kotlin, i don't know why this piece of code is not working.

This is my retrofit client

```swift
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://89a6t4gtke.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/Prod/"

    val instance : IApi by lazy{
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        retrofit.create(IApi::class.java)
    }
```

This is my response class

```
data class DefaultResponse(val message: String) {}
```

This is my response:

```swift
    {
        "message": "GET"
    }
```

Interface

```swift
    interface IApi {
        @GET("hello")
        fun returnHello():Call<DefaultResponse>
    }
```

The call

```swift
    toast_button.setOnClickListener{
        RetrofitClient.instance
            .returnHello()
            .enqueue(object: Callback<DefaultResponse>{
                override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<DefaultResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,t.message + "bla",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<DefaultResponse>,response: Response<DefaultResponse>) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "empty?",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                }
            })
    }
```

No toast messages show, i had an error show once when i made my api just return a string and not a json string but now there is no error as i fixed it.

Comment: I can't understand clearly, Do you have any toast in screen? I mean, is your onFailure or OnResponse called?

Comment: no toast anwers at all

Comment: Probably because you haven't called `show` on your `Toast` in `onResponse` function

Comment: Thanks you  @mightyWOZ thats it :)

Answer (score -1):

You should change to your Retrofit Client as following code;

```
class RetrofitClient {
        companion object {
            fun getClient(): Retrofit {
                return Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl("https://89a6t4gtke.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/Prod/")
                    .build()
            }
        }
    }
```

Then add this in your activity ;

```
 val service = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(IApi::class.java)
 val call = service.returnHello()

val resp: DefaultResponse? = call.clone().execute().body()
    if (resp != null) {
        println("your response is -> $resp")
    }
```